# Is the default value for enum class always 0?

Tags: visual-c++, enums, visual-studio-2019

Take this code:

```
enum class LIST_ICON_INDEX
{
    None = 0,
    DigitalMedia,
    Talk,
    ExcludedTalk
};
```

Do I have to include `= 0` there? I have seen some answers about `enum` and the ones about `enum class` are very verbose answers where I can't actually see the clarification about the starting value.

Comment: Like in regular enums, setting the first value to zero is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Enums should have zero value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1008?view=vs-2019):

> The default value of an uninitialized enumeration, just like other
>   value types, is zero. By default, if the value of the first
>   enumeration member is not set in the declaration, its value is zero.

Unless you specify otherwise in the definition of the enumeration, the initial enumerator always has the value zero and the value of each subsequent enumerator is one greater than the previous enumerator.

You do not need to specify a starting value of 0, it defaults to 0.